# Computation of parametric integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am trying to compute the integral

```
Integrate[(g^(u^(g - 1)))/(1 + u^g), {u, 0, t}]
```

but as an answer I get my input expression. There must be something wrong with parameters but even if I give values to `t` or `g` mathematica'a answer is the same: it just gives me back my input expression...

My output is

[image]

How can I compute this integral?

Comment: Same in v8. When you have numerical values for t and g you can use `NIntegrate`

Comment: you probably will need to do it numerically. Do you think you should have a closed form solution?

Comment: It seems for fixed values (I tried `g=2`) it works.

Comment: The only way I can get a value is when I give values to g and t. But I would like to have a closed form solution.

Comment: @chris: You are right... If I use g=2 I get a value. If I use g=4 I don't...In particular if I use `NIntegrate` with `t` being a limit of integration I can't have a solution.

Comment: Thano, is there some reason you expect a closed-form solution in general? It looks unlikely (but of course could still exist)

Comment: @acl: To be honest I would be happy if there was a closed form, but it seems that there isn't...It's OK, I can live with that!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to integrate `(g(u^(g - 1)))/(1 + u^g)` instead?  It would be a whole lot easier ... :-).

Comment: @whuber: You are right... It would be a lot easier. But unfortunately, this is what I have to compute...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this integral can be calculated symbolically only for special integer arguments `g`.   One can use e.g. `Assumptions` in `Integrate` :

```
Integrate[(g^(u^(g - 1)))/(1 + u^g), {u, 0, t}, Assumptions -> g == # && t > 0] & /@ Range[4]
```

> ```
> {Log[1 + t], 
>  I 2^(-1 - I) (Cos[Log[4]] ExpIntegralEi[-I Log[2]] - ExpIntegralEi[I Log[2]] + 
>  ExpIntegralEi[(I + t) Log[2]] - ExpIntegralEi[(-I + t) Log[2]] (Cos[Log[4]] + I Sin[Log[4]])
>   + I ExpIntegralEi[-I Log[2]] Sin[Log[4]]), 
>  Integrate[g^u^(-1 + g)/(1 + u^g), {u, 0, t}, Assumptions -> g == 3 && t > 0], 
>  Integrate[g^u^(-1 + g)/(1 + u^g), {u, 0, t}, Assumptions -> g == 4 && t > 0]}
> ```

We can see that only for `g == 1` or `g == 2` we can get exact results. For `g` rational e.g. `g == 3/2` we can't compute symbolically this integral either. For other values of `g` you could use `Nintegrate`to find numerical results.`Integrate` hasn't been changed in `version 9`, nethertheless some improvements of the core functionality has been described in [Enhanced Core Algorithms](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/enhanced-core-algorithms/). To find out more interesting remarks on `Integrate` I recommend to read [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html), especially this paragraph : Differentiation and Integration, where it says e.g. that the algorithms in `Mathematica` cover all of the indefinite integrals in standard reference books such as Gradshteyn-Ryzhik as well as that `Integrate` uses about 500 pages of `Mathematica` code and 600 pages of `C` code.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! It seems that there isn't a closed form... so the assumptions are vital! Thank you!

Comment: You could evaluate the integral numerically over a range of values of $g$ and interpolate that to get a working "closed form" function. Parameterize it as $g = \exp(\gamma)$ and evaluate it at roughly equally-spaced values of $\gamma$. To see what's going on, look at `LogLinearPlot[
 NIntegrate[(g^(u^(g - 1)))/(1 + u^g), {u, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50], {g, 0.01, 100000}, 
 PlotRange -> {Full, Full}]` (and be prepared to wait a minute or two: the extra precision is needed for values of $g$ greater than $1000$ or so, for obvious reasons). (The limit at $g\to\infty$ is $1$.)